# How to use post from HttpPost in 4.4.2?

Tags: json, apache, httpurlconnection, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm working for hours on this problem but got totally stucked. The following code is running perfectly on my test device with Android 4.1.2, but I can't get it to work with the second device
running 4.4.2. I read moving from `Apache httpClient` to `HttpURLConnection` solves the problem for some people, but I am also using the `GET`-method wich works fine. I already tried to add headers, as mentioned on sites I found. That did not work. So can you please help me in getting this working on Android 4.4.2 or give me a hint to the right direction? Thanks.

```
 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
.
.
.
 DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);                
 httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
 HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
 HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
 is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @LordRaydenMK i dont get any Java Errors, but libc [NET] getaddrinfo is complaining. On 4.1.2 i get something like DNS resolved for my spezified URL, I think here maybe the Problem.

Comment: @LordRaydenMK incoming traffic on svr is not correct.

Comment: @all this code is working too on 4.4.2, i figured out that there was something wrong in the List<NameValuePair>, depending on which crop app i use to create a Image in tis list. So the crop apps differ from 4.4.2 to 4.1.2 and maybe on manufacturer too. Thanks @ LordRaydenMK

Comment: @kox this sounds like a good reason to delete this question, because this is not helpful to anybody.

Answer (score 0):

set the following tag in the oncreate() method.

```
<i>StrictMode.enableDefaults(); </i>
```

extension.  now it will works fine..